# Calculating surface integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Consider the manifold $M=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3:3y+3xz^2-z^3=3\}$, and $Z=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3:x^2+z^2\le2, x>0,z\ge0\}$

How can I calculate the surface of $\mu(Z \cap M)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to compute the surface area of $Z \cap M$?

In that case, you should first parameterise your surface in the form $(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v))$, where $u,v$ are parameters. For example, we could first parameterise the quarter cylinder $Z$ by taking

$$x = u\cos v \qquad \qquad z = u\sin v \qquad \qquad u \in [0,\sqrt 2] \; \; \; \; v \in \bigg[0,\frac{\pi}{2} \bigg]$$

Then rewrite the equation for $M$ as $y = 1 - xz^2 + \frac 13 z^3$, so that $y$ must be

$$y = 1-u^3\cos v \sin^2 v+ \frac 13 u^3 \sin^3 v$$

That is, your surface $Z \cap M$ can be parameterised as

$$(x,y,z) = \bigg(u\cos v, 1-u^3\cos v \sin^2 v+ \frac 13 u^3 \sin^3 v, u\sin v \bigg) \qquad u \in [0,\sqrt 2] \; \; \; \; v \in \bigg[0,\frac{\pi}{2} \bigg]$$

> **Definition:**
>
> The surface area of a surface of the form $\mathbf r = (x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v))$, $(u,v) \in R$ is defined as $$\iint_{(u,v) \in R}\bigg|\frac{\partial \mathbf r}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial \mathbf r}{\partial v} \bigg| \, dudv$$

Now we just need to go through and do the computation.

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \mathbf r}{\partial u} & = \big(\cos v , -3u^2 \cos v \sin^2 v + u^2\sin^3v, \sin v \big) \\
\frac{\partial \mathbf r}{\partial v} & = \big(-u\sin v , -2u^3\cos^2 v \sin v + u^3\sin^3 v + u^3\sin^2 v \cos v , u \cos v \big) \\
\frac{\partial \mathbf r}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial \mathbf r}{\partial v} & = \big(-u^3\sin^2 v , -u , -2u^3\cos v \sin v + u^3 \sin^2 v \big) \\
... &
\end{align}

I leave the remaining details to you.

Comment: Thanks! I struggled with with the parameterization. Are we using some sort of cylindrical coordinates $(x,y,z)\to(r \cos \phi, r \sin \phi, z)$ but with $(x,y,z)\to(r \cos \phi, y, r \sin \phi)$ instead? So we can express $x$ and $z$ in terms of $r$ and $\phi$? (or as you did in terms of $u$ and $v$) This confused me because with the 'original' cylindrical coordinates I don't get rid of $z$.

Comment: Yeah, kind of. I think your confusion is caused by what is usually known as the "cylindrical coordinates". That is a set of coordinates that allows you to parameterise a 3D surface (since it has 3 parameters). Here, we have a surface (2D) so its not quite the same

Comment: One further question: in lecture we used $\sqrt{det( \nabla r^T \nabla r)}$ where $\nabla r^T$ is the gradient of $r$ transposed and $\nabla r$ is the gradient of $r$. Is this the same as $|\frac{\partial r}{\partial u}\times \frac{\partial r}{\partial v}|$?

Comment: I think that’s the generalisation to $n$ dimensions. The formula I have here only works for a 2D surface in 3D